# Windows form save textbox input to list in different class using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, list

C# windows form
How to save text from textboxes into list when list is in a different class.
I have a form1 with a number of textboxes. I want the input to be saved in a list that is in a different class.
I ahve the code in form1

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    minLista.add(textBox1.Text);
    Form2 Form1 = new Form2();
    this.Hide();
    Form1.Show();
}
```

in the other class I have

```
List <string> minLista = new List<string>();
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the other class? Have you instantiated it? My suggestion would be to make minLista a public property.

Comment: What error are you getting that makes you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: I have not instansiated it. How do I do that?

Comment: I get the error that minLista does not exist in the current context

Comment: is `List <string> minLista = new List<string>();` in form2?

Comment: minLista is in a new class called class1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make minlista public

```
public List<string> minLista = new List<string>();
```

Then use

```
 public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Classname a = new Classname();
    a.minLista.add(textBox1.Text);
    Form2 Form1 = new Form2();
    this.Hide();
    Form1.Show();
}
```

Where is `Classname` is the name of the class where you declared `minLista`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43250/discussion-between-christmas-unicorn-and-user3076791)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming minList is a public property in Form2.cs you should do something like

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThirdClass newthirdClass = new ThirdClass();
        newthirdClass.MinLista = new List<string>();
        newthirdClass.MinLista.Add(textBox1.Text);
        Form2 myForm2 = new Form2(newthirdClass);
        this.Hide();
        myForm2 .Show();
    }
```

Keep in mind that the convention is for properties (like I propose you for minLista) to start with a capital letter (i.e. MinLista)

**EDIT**

Since you need it to be in a third class I would do this

```
public class ThirdClass
{
  public List<string> MinLista {get; set;}
}

public Form Form2
{
   private List<string> minLista;

   public Form2(List<string> mlist)
   {
      minLista = mlist;
   }

}
```

This way you inject the object you created (which has the reference to the list you want) to Form2.

Comment: How would you write the code to make the list minLista public?

Comment: I changed the code slightly above and then in Form2 you should have a property like public List<string> minLista {get; set;}

Comment: Okay so in the class I write the code you just wrote under public class class1 {
public list <string> minLista {get; set;}
}

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The code I wrote is in class1 (i.e. Form1) and the public List<string> ... is in class2 (i.e. Form2)

Comment: Okay I have a couple of forms and then I added a class. I might have done something wrong but can't you add a class and write the code for the list in there?

Comment: so you need the list to be in a third class? And you need to have access to it from both Form1 and Form2?